# running file ruby on whenever/crontjob ruby

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever

how to running file ruby in whenever, in this case i'm not using rails. If in example rails code, i'm only must running this code and it's work :

example in rails :

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
end
```

but if i want to running file with extenstion .rb without rails, how do that :

example similiar code like this :

```
 every 3.hours do
   runner "ruby test.rb"
 end
```

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `command` instead of `runner`:

```
every 3.hours do
  command "ruby test.rb"
end
```

Hope this helps.